# Sequelize COUNT inside INCLUDE Associations return error aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I'm using **Sequelize** in my ExpressJS with SQL Server. I've two tables called PersonalInfo and ProductBuy it has relation PersonalInfo hasMany ProductBuy.

Here is the associations my model:

### PersonalInfo.js

```
PersonalInfo.hasMany(models.ProductBuy, {
   foreignKey: 'member_id',
   sourceKey: 'id'
});
```

### ProductBuy.js

```
ProductBuy.belongsTo(models.PersonalInfo, {
   foreignKey: 'member_id',
   targetKey: 'id'
});
```

I wanna get *ProductBuy* count of each *user*.
Expected Result:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "ProductBuys": [
                {
                    "total_active": 3
                }
             ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "ProductBuys": [
                {
                    "total_active": 1
                }
             ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my function in controller:

```
getAll: function (req, res) {
    PersonalInfo.findAll({
        attributes: ['id'],
        include: [
            {
                model: ProductBuy,
                attributes: [
                    [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('member_id')), 'total_active']
                ],
                separate:true,
                where: {
                    status: ['Aktif', 'Expired']
                },
                group:['member_id', 'id']
            }
        ],
    }).then(value => {
        responseUtil.success(res, value)
    })
}
```

but, this is what I got

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "ProductBuys": [
                {
                    "total_active": 1
                },
                {
                    "total_active": 1
                },
                {
                    "total_active": 1
                }
             ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "ProductBuys": [
                {
                    "total_active": 1
                }
             ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I think that's happen because I GROUP BY it by `member_id` and `id`, but if I remove the `id` it will cause error like this

> Column 'ProductBuy.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

How do I can achive this. Thankyou